# Single output to sequence LED

Tags: led, digital-logic, diodes, decoder

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f40lXt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Setup**

- Only one IN can be set HIGH at a time by a micro-controller

**Requirement**

If IN{i} = 1, LED {1 to i} should be **ON**

**Problem**

- I use too many diodes here. Is there a simpler solution to convert one number to a sequence of numbers (1 to N)? I need the lights to be something like a digital meter.

Comment: Back up a bit.  I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: @ScottSeidman As far as I understand, the requirement is to light up  the number of LEDs corresponding to the high `IN` index. With less diodes.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I connected a decoder from arduino to control 16 LEDs from 4 outputs. Since the decoder can only have one LED ON at a time, I want to modify it to glow LEDs like a sequence, like a LED audio meter.

Comment: I suggest an unambiguous truth table.  I still don't understand "...to convert one number to a sequence of numbers (1 to N)"

Comment: Are you saying that you don't actually want 4 LEDs, but actually 16 LEDs, arranged so that from 0 to all 16 will be ON, using no more than the already existing 4 outputs from your Arduino that you are using now?

Comment: @EugeneSh. If an input i is on, I want to glow all LEDs less than or equal to i.

Comment: @MaheshKarthikeyan Your going to need some digital logic, plus you've never specified your input, is it from a microprocessor? Comparators?

Comment: @laptop2d the input is from a 3 to 8 decoder controlled by an Arduino

Comment: @MaheshKarthikeyan: Please put all the relevant information in the original question so that all the required information is in the one place and replace the "OUT" nodes with the ground symbols. Include part numbers and links to datasheets.

Comment: Since you control your LEDs with Arduino, why simply not sweep output values in range 1 to N fast enough so N LEDs appear lit?

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit is poor because the further up the chain you go the more voltage drop will occur on the first few LEDs. Also where are your LED current limiting resistors?

Instead, since the LEDs are controlled by a micro-controller you "multiplex" them. This means scanning all 16 LEDs faster than the eye can see - maybe 50 times a second - and turning each one on as required for a short high-current pulse.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnM930.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. To light the first four LEDs the strobe sequence would be as shown.*

Check the datasheet for your LEDs and there should be a peak current rating typically giving the maximum pulse current, duration and duty cycle.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this statically is to use two [74HC595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf) shift register chips. Just connect one LED and one series resistor to each output, and daisy chain two chips (input to output and clocks/strobes in parallel).

The maximum current through the supply must be less than 70mA per chip so use something like 5mA per LED to calculate the resistors (40ma per chip).

You can then use three pins to control the shift registers- data, clock and strobe. Once you shift out the 16 bits you can go off and do something else. It's very similar to an SPI interface where the /CS is the strobe /MR on the '595.